# I have specific tabular data, how can I represent this with Polymer with 2 way binding?

Tags: data-binding, data-visualization, polymer, infinite-scroll

Are there any components built with polymer that allow displaying of tabular data? I would like something that compares with current UI grids out there.

I am interested in infinite scrolling and 2 way binding to json data in particular.

Comment: If the question said "I have specific tabular data X. How can I represent this with Polymer?" then more people would find the question on-topic. (There is only a fine line between "I'm not sure what code best solves my problem" and "I'm not sure what UI component to use" IMO.)

Answer (score 2):

One good place to look for such things is the [Component Kitchen](http://component.kitchen/)

Looking there I found [`aha-table`](http://component.kitchen/components/aha-table). It doesn't appear to have infinite-scrolling, but it lists pagination as a feature.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I am also creating some finance components for Polymer but for starts I am not sure whether to extend **core-input** or **paper-input** for a **money-input** component. Can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

Not a completely useful answer but here's what I'm aware of:

Seems that the team plans to add what you're looking for - https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/20

This might help you do something now - https://github.com/polymer/core-layout-grid

Comment: core-layout-grid is for screen layouts, not for tabular grids, if that makes any sense. The name is confusing, but it's not the right solution for this problem.